# creating the x variable in R studio problem

Tags: r, probability

I am just starting my online stats class and there is extremely little guidance. Here is the question:

*roll three dice, independently*

We want to calculate the probability of the following event

*A=The sum of the first two numbers obtained is larger than the third number obtained*

1. Write code that calculates the probability of A. Print a line that reads "x out of the 216 possible results are such that the sum of the first two dice is larger than the third, therefore its probability is pA", replacing x and pA by appropriate quantities. Store the number pA as a variable.

Here is what I have so far, it runs but the output makes no sense and I know it is incorrect. Any guidance would be great!

```
pA<-0
x<-0
for(i in 1:6){ 
  for(j in 1:6){
    for(k in 1:6){ 
      sumdigits<-i+j
      if (sumdigits>k) {pA<-pA+1}
      if (sumdigits>k) {x<-x+1}
      print(paste(x, "out of the 216 possible results are such that the sum of the first two dice is larger than the third, therefore its probability is", (pA)))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should print at the very end (outside of your for loops) because it seems like you are only looking for one answer (what is the probability of the event A occurring). Also, you might want to double check your pA formula (should be a fraction?). The simplest way would probably be to calculate pA after your loop.
Side note: you might also want to edit your question title because its very vague. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, the result "....therefore its probability is..."... this should be a number between 0 and 1 (or 0% and 100%). You are close but forgetting one step.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. Try rephrasing your code to the following:

```
x<-0
for(i in 1:6){ 
  for(j in 1:6){
    for(k in 1:6){ 
      sumdigits<-i+j
      if (sumdigits>k) {x<-x+1}
    }
  }
}

pA <- x/216
print(paste(x, "out of the 216 possible results are such that the sum of the first two dice is larger than the third, therefore its probability is", (pA)))
```

Output:

```
[1] "181 out of the 216 possible results are such that the sum of the first two dice is larger than the third, therefore its probability is 0.837962962962963"
```

The probability `pA` is defined as x/216, as stated in the print statement; this should therefore be calculated after your loops. Your print statement should therefore also come after your loops, as `pA` can only be calculated after you know `x`.